# facebook api, how to change the name of the category when u like something?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

i am trying to add a like button on my webpage and when i like something in facebook appears under `Website` category. I would like to change that. Any Ideas?

here is my fb like button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=app id here&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.xxx.com" ref="casting" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `og:type` meta property on your page. You can find available options [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types). For example:

`<meta property="og:type" content="athlete" />`

**Note** that the meta data will have to be defined in the `<head>` portion of your site (as all meta tags should) or Facebook will ignore it.

You might want to look into the [open graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to see some other stuff you can define for the "likes".

**Additionally note** that editing the `og:type` on a page which has received more than 10,000 likes will not be changed anymore as they have become fixed at that point.

As **fijter** noted below, Facebook looks for this meta data from the url which is used for the like button. If you have a like button with an url which you can't control, you won't be able to modify the meta data associated with it.

If your page has been liked already (but less than 10,000 times) and you change your meta data, run the [Facebook URL linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) tool to have Facebook refetch the meta data from your site.

Comment: Also note that the page containing the og:type should be the same page as called in the href tag, otherwise it probably won't work.

Comment: @fijter correct indeed. The metadata for the actual liked page is always used. So if you use an url which isn't the current page, Facebook fetches the meta data from the linked url.